# Weird Clojure Box - library (dll) issue

Tags: java, dll, clojure, slime, jacob

I am trying to use the JACOB library with Clojure using Clojure Box.

I have added this to my .emacs:

```
(setq swank-clojure-library-paths (list "c:/dev/dlls"))
```

`C:/dev/dlls/` contains the `jacob-1.14.3-x86.dll`.

I have added a `.clojure` dir to my `~/` dir and that contains the 
`jacob.jar`.

At the Clojure Box REPL, `(System/getProperty "java.class.path")` yields:

```
"c:/Program Files/Clojure Box/clojure/clojure.jar;c:/Program Files/Clojure Box/clojure-contrib/clojure-contrib.jar;;c:/Documents and Settings/mac009/Application Data/.clojure/jacob.jar"
```

and

```
"Settings/mac009/Application Data/.clojure/jacob.jar"
```

and `(System/getProperty "java.library.path")` yields:

```
"c:/dev/dlls"
```

If I start Clojure Box and issue `(import '(com.jacob.com Dispatch 
ComThread))`, the REPL just hangs.

Now for the weird part. If I kill the REPL and do "Alt-X slime" and 
answer no to "Create an additional *inferior-lisp*? (y or n)" and 
issue "(import '(com.jacob.com Dispatch ComThread))" it works! Even 
weirder is that this only "works" if I first issue "(import 
'(com.jacob.com Dispatch ComThread))" and make the REPL hang. If I 
just start Clojure Box and kill/restart the REPL without first issuing 
"(import '(com.jacob.com Dispatch ComThread))" it just hangs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

JACOB: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/

Clojure Box: 
http://clojure.bighugh.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to copy swank-clojure.jar to ~/clojure.

1. Put this in ~/.emacs:

   (setq swank-clojure-library-paths '("c:\dev\dlls"))
2. Create the directory C:\dev\dlls.
3. Copy the Jacob DLLs to C:\dev\dlls.
4. Create the directory ~/clojure.
5. Copy clojure.jar, clojure-contrib.jar and swank-clojure.jar to ~/clojure.
6. Start ClojureBox.

Versions:

- ClojureBox 1.2.0
- jacob-1.15-M4